# Convert coordinate string to float

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to convert a string coordinate with this format `50.3332W` to the equivalent float representation `-50.3332`.

At the moment I have something like this but it just replaces the `W` character and places the minus sign at the end.

```
NSString *newtest = [_myTextField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"W" withString:@"-"];
```

Any help on this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// *** Your string value ***
NSString *value = @"50.3332W";

// *** Remove `W` from string , convert it to float and make it negative by multiplying with -1. 
CGFloat floatValue = [[value stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"W" withString:@""] floatValue] * -1;

// ** Result negative float value without `W` **
NSLog(@"%f",floatValue);
```

Comment: He probably only wants it to be negative if it contains `W` as it seems a coordinate.

Comment: OP has not mentioned such thing, my post answer what OP has asked for.

Comment: According to the original question, he wanted to replace the `W` with a `-`. And you are always inserting the `-` regardless of the existence of the `W`. If your post answers that, it's a wrong answer.

Comment: This is strait forward and it works but W was just an example it may need to be S

Comment: Now you can customise according to your need for 'S', 'N', 'W' & 'E'.

Comment: No because even if there is no "W" for instance it still adds a "-".

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

```
- (float)coordinateToFloat:(NSString*)coordinateString {
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\\d+\\.?\\d+?)(W)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    NSString* prefixString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:coordinateString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, coordinateString.length) withTemplate:@"$2$1"];
    NSString* normalizedString = [prefixString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"W" withString:@"-"];
    return normalizedString.floatValue;
}
```

Then, you can call it like this:

```
[self coordinateToFloat:@"50.3332W"]; // Returns -50.3332
[self coordinateToFloat:@"50.3332"]; // Returns 50.3332
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uV2qK6/1)

Comment: Clever answer. Although the formatting makes it difficult to read.

Comment: @vype Why not? What did you try?

Comment: well i had to change it slightly to make it work for my textfield, but it just seems to crash when i change text1 to equal to mytextfield

Comment: @vype I update my answer so try `NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\\d+\\.?\\d+?)(W)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];`    `NSString *newtest1 = [[regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:_myTextField.text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, _myTextField.text.length) withTemplate:@"$2$1"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"W" withString:@"-"];` Why is crash message?

Comment: @Tim007 i'm trying to grab the current coordinates from my textfield and update it without the "W" and add the "-" but cant figure out how to connect your code to my textfields any idea?